# Lock and Unlock the file in C++

Tags: c++

In windows OS, in my C++ application, I have to protect the entire  file which is already existing and I should be able to do read and write operation against that file.

Before closing the file I should protect the file so that other than my application or any user cannot access that file?

How to achieve this in C++?

I am using

```
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On what platform?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? What is the *real* problem behind this question?

Comment: The only way to truly achieve this it to encrypt the file contents and keep the key to yourself (a subject that is also fraught with pitfalls)

Comment: @Lightness in windows platform

Comment: Add that detail into your question plz

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not provide file locking or file security functions so you have to rely on Platform API.
In Windows, it's [LockFileEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex) and [UnlockFileEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-unlockfileex) while the file is opened, and [File Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-security-and-access-rights) when the file is closed.

That said, security in Windows is a highly complex subject so you should describe what's the goal you are trying to achieve. I think you need to disallow other apps to read your file, so in that case, you have to encrypt the file with a password.

Comment: Can I use LockFileEx with MFC's CFile?

Comment: @user369287, yes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfile-class?view=vs-2017) but are you sure you want that sort of locking?

Comment: This link says https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfile  "If a process terminates with a portion of a file locked or closes a file that has outstanding locks, the locks are unlocked by the operating system."

Comment: @user369287 I don' think you need locks. Locks are for open handles only. Use CryptProtectData or something more advanced like Access Controls. Basically, you need to forget anything coming from linux.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that this is possible using standard C or C++ or with a `FILE*` object directly. Having said that Windows has the `LockFile`  and `UnlockFile` APIs and you can achieve the same thing on Posix systems with `fcntl`

Comment: This link says https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfile  "If a process terminates with a portion of a file locked or closes a file that has outstanding locks, the locks are unlocked by the operating system."